# Log file not found issue in Google Composer/Airflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

We are currently using Google Composer as our Airflow environment, and we have encountered an issue in our Dev environment. I would like to seek assistance in diagnosing and resolving this problem.
In our Dev environment, we have two schedulers and one worker, with the following specifications: scheduler_cpu: 2, scheduler_memory: 2, scheduler_storage: 0.5, and the worker has 2 CPUs and 8GB of memory. We have jobs running on an hourly basis.
Occasionally, we encounter the following error message:

```
  "*** Log file is not found: <path to log>
    *** The task might not have been executed, or the worker executing it might have finished abnormally (e.g., was evicted)."
    Please, refer https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/troubleshooting-dags#common_issues hints to learn what might be possibble for a missing log"
```

on the failed task log, but the actual log is present in the composer environment.
We have investigated the issue by checking the worker, scheduler, and Airflow health status at the time of failure to check if this has to do with the dev env spec, but they all appear to be functioning correctly. We have also examined the Composer logs for any indications of a signal sent to the worker that could prevent it from reporting its status, but we have not found any relevant information.

We are seeking advice from the community regarding this issue. If anyone has encountered a similar problem or has insights on how to diagnose and resolve it, we would greatly appreciate your assistance.

We are on Compose 2.4.3

Thank you for your professionalism and expertise in advance

Comment: how did you managed to fix this issue?